# When reading stream, why not stop iterating when 0 bytes read

Tags: java

The standard idiom when reading from a stream is to check for EOF (-1):

```
while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
```

This seems pretty standard - I checked source for popular libraries like Apache Commons and it seems to be the defacto standard.

Why do we not stop at 0 as well?  Wouldn't `> -1` be better?  Why do whatever work is in the loop when we didn't read anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically because it would be pointless. Look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-):

> If the length of `b` is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into `b`.

So unless you're passing in an empty buffer (which is basically a bug in pretty much all cases; I personally wish the method would throw an exception in that case) the return value will *never be 0*. It will block for at least one byte to be read (in which case the return value will be 1 or more), or for the end of the stream to be reached (in which case the return value will be -1).

Comment: Shouldn’t that last bit read “in which case the return value will be -1”?

Comment: @VGR: Whoops, yes - fixed :)